# Why does the value of this variable go over 256 when I programmed it not to?

Tags: c#

Here's my code:

```
 public void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Random rnd = new System.Random();
        int ci = 1;
            int di=1;
                int fi=1;
        int c = rnd.Next(1, 254);
        int d = rnd.Next(1, 254);
                for (int f = rnd.Next(1, 254); f < 255; f+=fi)
                {

                    this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(c, d, f);
                    Application.DoEvents();
                    if (c == 254 || c == 0) { ci *= -1; }
                    if (f == 254 || f == 0 || f == 50 || f == 100 || f == 150 || f == 200)
                    {
                        d += di;
                    } 
                    if (d == 255 || d == 0)
                    {
                        di *= -1;
                    }
                    if (f==254|| f == 0)
                    {
                        fi *= -1;
                    }
                    if (d == 254)
                    {
                        c += ci;
                    }
                }
     }
```

The error that pops up is that the value of d goes over 256.

However, when I run this in the debugger, I can't see any situation where d would go over 256. When d is 255, di becomes negative therefore d += di would decrease the value of d. Therefore it is impossible for d to ever go above 255. Therefore it is confusing when the debugger tells me that d just went to 256.

Can anyone explain to me why this happens?

Comment: How did you mean to _end_ your `for` loops? Did you expect the criterion `< 255` to be important? Suppose the inner-most `for` loop never ends. How are the outer `for` loops relevant then?

Comment: Your are right, they are superfluous. I deleted them now. The problem remains.

Comment: Can you edit your code to reflect its latest state and repost?

Comment: I edited the code 1 minute ago to reflect its latest state.

Comment: (When you make a comment to someone else's comment, and that someone is not the one who wrote the post (answer/question), you should use a `@` followed by the nick of the person you are talking to. That way the receiver will be notified you commented on his comment.)

Comment: @user2108462  Random.Next(1,254) will produce values in the range 1..253. Is that what you intended?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose `f` can never go above 254 in the inner loop, and `d` is 255.

The first time the following code is executed, `di` will become negative. However, since the innermost loop continues executing `d` has not changed, so on the next pass through the innermost loop `d` is *still* 255 so this condition sets `di` back to positive.

```
if (d == 255 || d == 0)
{
    di *= -1;
}
```

I believe the following is closer to what you intended for each of the blocks containing `variable *= -1;` (I used `d` specifically):

```
if (d == 255)
{
    di = -1;
}
else if (d == 0)
{
    di = 1;
}
```

Comment: Aha! I understand it now. Since the condition for d += di is not always met after executing di *= -1, there is a chance that when the condition for d+= di is met, di has been changed to 1 again. Thank you.